# Windows Network Load Balancing Duplicates UDP Packages?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, powershell, load-balancing, wireshark, udp

## Background

I have two **Windows Server 2012R2** VMs (each with one NIC) listening on port 514 for Syslog UDP messages, which process and then persist the messages to a database. I tried setting up [Network Load Balancing](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb734896.aspx) to distribute the Syslog traffic between the two of them.

When I tested the configuration by sending **one** UDP packet from PowerShell to the *clustered* IP, I noticed that I would get **two** syslog entries in the database. At first, I thought *each* host had received and processed the packet separately, so I added a tag to both so they would persist their dedicated IP Address as well. From that I knew I was actually getting two packets from the *same* host.

Using Wireshark I can confirm that two packets are received by the interface, both for the same IP. But if I send the UDP packet to the *dedicated* IP, I will only receive one packet. Is this normal behavior for NLB to duplicate a package on the interface? For load balancing, this seems counterproductive because the cluster then has to process two packets for every one packet sent. How do I configure NLB to not give the receiving host two of the same packet?

### My NLB Configuration

#### Cluster Properties:

```
Cluster IP Address: 192.168.1.100  
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0  
Full Internet name: mysyslogcluster.local  
Network Address: 03-bf-c0-a8-01-64  
Cluster Operation Mode: Multicast  
Port Rules: 0-513 (disabled), 514 (udp), 515-65535 (disabled)
```

#### Host 1 Properties

```
IP Address: 192.168.1.1
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Load Weight: Equal
```

#### Host 2 Properties

```
IP Address: 192.168.1.2
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Load Weight: Equal
```

#### Port 514 Rule

```
Protocols: UDP
Filtering mode: Multiple host
Affinity: None
```

### Testing

I have Wireshark installed on both hosts, with the filter: `udp port 514`

I wrote a PowerShell function to send a Syslog Message to a certain IP and Port

```
function Get-UdpClient($IP, $Port){
    $UDPClient = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient
    $UDPClient.Connect($IP, $Port)
    return $UDPClient
}
function Send-Syslog($UDPClient, $facility = 5, $severity = 7, $program = "PSSyslogGen", $hostname = $env:COMPUTERNAME, $category = "TEST", $message){        
    $priority = ($facility * 8) + $severity    
    $datetime = Get-Date -Format "MMM dd HH:mm:ss"    
    $FSyslogMessageStr = "<{0}>{1} {2} {3} {4}: {5}" -f $priority, $datetime, $hostname, $program, $category, $message    
    $SyslogMessageBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($FSyslogMessageStr)    
    $resp = $UDPClient.Send($SyslogMessageBytes, $SyslogMessageBytes.Length)    
}
```

If I run the command in Powershell on a separate host:

```
PS C:>$client = Get-UDPClient -IP "192.168.1.100" -Port 514
PS C:>Send-Syslog -UDPClient $client -message "Test NLB"
```

I will see in Wireshark:

```
No. Time    Source  Destination Protocol    Length  Info
1   0.000000    192.168.1.200   192.168.1.100   Syslog  115 SYSLOG.DEBUG: Jun 29 12:00:00 PSSyslogGen HOST-NAME TEST: Test NLB
2   0.000077    192.168.1.200   192.168.1.100   Syslog  115 SYSLOG.DEBUG: Jun 29 12:00:00 PSSyslogGen HOST-NAME TEST: Test NLB
```

And then if I run it again, but this time to the dedicated IP

```
PS C:>$client = Get-UDPClient -IP "192.168.1.1" -Port 514
PS C:>Send-Syslog -UDPClient $client -message "Test NLB"
```

I'll just get one packet in Wireshark

```
3   10.384867   192.168.1.200   192.168.1.1 Syslog  115 SYSLOG.DEBUG: Jun 29 12:00:10 PSSyslogGen HOST-NAME TEST: Test NLB
```

#### edit 1

I can confirm that the same behavior is exhibited for TCP packets. I've also tried configuring NLB with Unicast Cluster Operation Mode and experienced the same problem.

Wireshark on the other host shows no traffic.

In sum, I will get **2** packets on a *single* host through a *single* IP for every **1** packet sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hypervisor had improperly load-balanced NICs, which were causing all broadcast packets to duplicate. Disabling one of the Hypervisor's NICs solved the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "Disabling one of the Hypervisor's NICs"?